# android: Custom SimpleCursorAdapter does not load all data

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

In need of assistance,  I have a listview activity which I want to display couple of textfields per item plus 2 buttons (like contacts app having a call button and a text message button.  Reading tutorials I found out how to get the buttons to be clickable, but now my textviews (all except 1) don't display any data other then the stock text I've left in the layout file.  The 1 text view does display the data I require it to.  No where in my custom SCA do I feed it specific data so I'm assuming it happens in the background.

My R.id.company_address_details_phone loads the needed data without any manipulation on my part, but non of the other TextViews in my ViewHolder display any data.  My For loop attached to my call button does output data from my cursor so I know it's not that I'm missing data.  Any and all help is appreciated.

As a side note, when first wrote the code and did not use a custom SimpleCursorAdapter all my text views populated as expected (i just couldnt click buttons).  This leads me to assume that my CompanyActivity class has no errors but that I'm missing something in my CompanyDetailsCursroAdapter class.

****EDIT******
So I'm answering my own question after I looked back and tried something.  non of my views where being populated, I just had one of my views set with default text that made it appear as if it was pulled from my DB.  I'm now populating my views with data from the cursor adapter passed to my custom cursor adapter using the below code.  I would like to know if this is the best way of doing it or is there a more streamlined or android approved method.

```
            viewHolder.addressTextView.setText(companyDetailsCursor.getString(companyDetailsCursor.getColumnIndex("AddressStreet")));
        viewHolder.cityTextView.setText(companyDetailsCursor.getString(companyDetailsCursor.getColumnIndex("AddressCity")));
        viewHolder.stateTextView.setText(companyDetailsCursor.getString(companyDetailsCursor.getColumnIndex("AddressState")));
        viewHolder.zipTextView.setText(companyDetailsCursor.getString(companyDetailsCursor.getColumnIndex("AddressZip")));
        viewHolder.phoneTextView.setText(companyDetailsCursor.getString(companyDetailsCursor.getColumnIndex("AddressPhone")));
```

CompanyDetailsCursorAdapter.java

```
public class CompanyDetailsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements Filterable{
private final Context context;
private int layout;
Cursor companyDetailsCursor;

public CompanyDetailsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.companyDetailsCursor = c;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView addressTextView;
    protected TextView cityTextView;
    protected TextView stateTextView;
    protected TextView zipTextView;
    protected TextView phoneTextView;

    protected ImageButton callButton;
    protected ImageButton mapButton;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_address_details, null);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.addressTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_address_details_street);
        viewHolder.cityTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_address_details_city);
        viewHolder.stateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_address_details_state);
        viewHolder.zipTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_address_details_zip);
        viewHolder.phoneTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_address_details_phone);

        viewHolder.callButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_address_details_call_button);

        viewHolder.callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                companyDetailsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                if (RouteTrackerGlobal.APP_DEBUG) { Log.d(RouteTrackerGlobal.APP_TAG,"getview position set to " + String.valueOf(position));}
                for (int i = 0; i < companyDetailsCursor.getColumnCount();i++){
                    Log.i(RouteTrackerGlobal.APP_TAG, companyDetailsCursor.getString(i));
                }
            }

        });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder  = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

CompanyActivity.java

```
public class CompanyActivity extends ListActivity {
DbAdapter dbAdapter;
int companyID;

Context context = this;

Cursor companyDetailsCursor;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);

    dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.company_activity);

    Bundle companyActivityBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    companyID = companyActivityBundle.getInt("CompanyID");

    ListView list = getListView();

    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    dbAdapter.close();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    dbAdapter.open();
    super.onResume();
    loadDetails();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    //TODO: When item in list clicked, call activity to display address and directions
}

public void loadDetails() {
    TextView companyLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.company_activity_company_label);

    companyDetailsCursor = dbAdapter.getCompanyDetails(companyID);
    startManagingCursor(companyDetailsCursor);

    companyDetailsCursor.moveToFirst();

    companyLabel.setText(companyDetailsCursor.getString(companyDetailsCursor.getColumnIndex("CompanyName")));

    String[] columns = new String[] {"AddressPhone", "AddressStreet", "AddressCity", "AddressState", "AddressZip"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.company_address_details_phone, R.id.company_address_details_street, R.id.company_address_details_city, R.id.company_address_details_state, R.id.company_address_details_zip};

    CompanyDetailsCursorAdapter companyDetailsAdapter = new CompanyDetailsCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.company_address_details, companyDetailsCursor, columns, to);
    setListAdapter(companyDetailsAdapter);


}
```

}

Company_Address_Details.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_address_details_phone"
            style="@style/company_address_listview"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/company_address_details_phone_default" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/company_address_details_call_button"
            style="@style/company_address_listview"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"
            android:contentDescription="@string/company_address_details_phone_hint"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/company_address_details_call_button1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_address_details_street"
                    style="@style/company_address_listview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/company_address_details_street_default" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_address_details_city"
                    style="@style/company_address_listview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/company_address_details_city_default" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_address_details_state"
                    style="@style/company_address_listview"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/company_address_details_state_default" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_address_details_zip"
                    style="@style/company_address_listview"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/company_address_details_zip_default" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>







        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/company_address_details_call_button1"
            style="@style/company_address_listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/company_address_details_phone_hint"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```